# retrieve id3 informations from remote mp3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, taglib, id3

I need to get these information not from a file located on my machine, but on another one.

In general I'm able to get these infos in this way:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File.open("myfile.mp3") do |file|

    tag = file.tag

    "Artist:     "      +   tag.artist      + " " +
    "Title:      "      +   tag.title       + " " +
    "Album:      "      +   tag.album       + " "

end
```

... but if I open a link to the file like "http:// .../myfile.mp3" It doesn't work. Why?

Is there a different way to resolve it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My files are on S3 and i'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TagLib only works on files on the local filesystem. To retrieve tags from remote files, you'd first have to download that file to your local disk.

Answer (score 1):

So a **path** to the file system should be given to the `TagLib::MPEG::File.open` param, not a **url**.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But It was answered four years ago.